# Carousel image size for multiple screen soze

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am designing a full screen carousel in html and i would like to know what is the ideal size the image should have so that it resizes on all screens sizes without distortion

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Bootstrap 3.3.0</h3>
        <p>Responsive Moving Box Carousel Demo</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">   
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
        </div>


       <nav>
            <ul class="control-box pager">
                <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
       <!-- /.control-box -->   

    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->          

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS

```
/* Global */


img { max-width:100%; }

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease; 
    }

a:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE7 */
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-decoration: none;
}



body{
    border-top:0;
    background:#c4e17f;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,#c4e17f,#c4e17f 12.5%,#f7fdca 12.5%,#f7fdca 25%,#fecf71 25%,#fecf71 37.5%,#f0776c 37.5%,#f0776c 50%,#db9dbe 50%,#db9dbe 62.5%,#c49cde 62.5%,#c49cde 75%,#669ae1 75%,#669ae1 87.5%,#62c2e4 87.5%,#62c2e4);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left,#c4e17f,#c4e17f 12.5%,#f7fdca 12.5%,#f7fdca 25%,#fecf71 25%,#fecf71 37.5%,#f0776c 37.5%,#f0776c 50%,#db9dbe 50%,#db9dbe 62.5%,#c49cde 62.5%,#c49cde 75%,#669ae1 75%,#669ae1 87.5%,#62c2e4 87.5%,#62c2e4);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,#c4e17f,#c4e17f 12.5%,#f7fdca 12.5%,#f7fdca 25%,#fecf71 25%,#fecf71 37.5%,#f0776c 37.5%,#f0776c 50%,#db9dbe 50%,#db9dbe 62.5%,#c49cde 62.5%,#c49cde 75%,#669ae1 75%,#669ae1 87.5%,#62c2e4 87.5%,#62c2e4);background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#c4e17f,#c4e17f 12.5%,#f7fdca 12.5%,#f7fdca 25%,#fecf71 25%,#fecf71 37.5%,#f0776c 37.5%,#f0776c 50%,#db9dbe 50%,#db9dbe 62.5%,#c49cde 62.5%,#c49cde 75%,#669ae1 75%,#669ae1 87.5%,#62c2e4 87.5%,#62c2e4)
}

.thumbnails li> .fff .caption { 
    background:#fff !important; 
    padding:10px
}

/* Page Header */
.page-header {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: -30px -40px 40px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page-header h3 {
    line-height: 0.88rem;
    color: #000;
}

ul.thumbnails { 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}



/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
    color: #444;
}

.caption p {  
    color: #999;
}



/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-control{
    background: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 18px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding: 4px 10px 0px;
    position: static;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
}



/* Mobile Only */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .page-header, .control-box {
        text-align: center;
    } 
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .caption {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}


li { list-style-type:none;}

::selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0; }
::-moz-selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

JS

```
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000
    })
  });
```